# Webassembly memory leak

Tags: javascript, c++, c, memory-leaks, webassembly

I have webassembly code running and i can clearly see some memory leaks. The code is written in C and when I compile with gcc and run the C code there is no memory leak. In the browser javascript just calls a `webassembly` function (the same function that I tested in C code) and runs it. Using both htop and task manager for Chrome I can see the memory growing during a "for" cycle of that function, but I debugged that same cycle in C using `valgrind` and as I said before there are no memory leaks. When I compile using `webassembly` I use this command:

```
emcc llab/*.c client_side/*.c -s WASM=1 -s ASSERTIONS=1 -s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1 -s USE_PTHREADS=1 -s WASM_MEM_MAX=4GB -s PTHREAD_POOL_SIZE=4 --preload-file data --no-heap-copy -O3 -lm -lpthread -o index.js
```

During that function the client should create some threads and do some stuff. As i said, in C that function doesn't create any memory leaks, is this a bug of `wasm`, Chrome or what else could be?

Furthemore the function does what it is supposed to do, but there is this memory leak that is giving me troubles because I need to iterate that function more and more times. The process created by that function allocates immediatly aboout 800Mb and then when it does the "for" cycle the memory grows with about 1 Mb (more or less) each step (sometimes more sometimes less). As i said i debugged the code in C and there are no memory leaks. The for cycle creates and joins threads which are the core of the function. Any help is appreciated. I can't post the code because is too long is based on a library built in 2 years in C, but I can give my word that in C there are no memory leaks.

Comment: try browsers - if it leaks everywhere, then it's the code - if it leaks only in Chrome, I wouldn't be surprised at all

Comment: i m gonna do that thx.

Comment: just to let you know, i tried with microsoft edge and guess what... there is no memory leak. It's chrome....

Comment: was that with edge based on chrome or the old edge?

Comment: based on chrome